# Cannot install mysqlclient on MacOS

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip

I have been trying to integrate mysql into my Flask project. I recently moved to a MacOS so having a hard time installing the dependencies. I tried to download mysql client using pip but gives the following error

```
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/L053984/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/L053984/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/L053984/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/m2/4ys_q90d1530pr6h8c70xj340000gp/T/pip-build-env-0g_2cgj8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/m2/4ys_q90d1530pr6h8c70xj340000gp/T/pip-build-env-0g_2cgj8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/m2/4ys_q90d1530pr6h8c70xj340000gp/T/pip-build-env-0g_2cgj8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip
```

I installed brew as well as MacPorts but not able to solve the issue. Help would be appreciated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you skipped following the instructions which are here: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Answer (score 13):

This doc helped me: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient

I followed the section below.

---

#### macOS (Homebrew)

Install MySQL and mysqlclient:

```
# Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
$ brew install mysql pkg-config
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

If you don't want to install MySQL server, you can use mysql-client instead:

```
# Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
$ brew install mysql-client pkg-config
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

---

I'm using MariaDB docker image, so I didn't want to install mysql in my Mac so I followed the second instruction.

Comment: On Sonoma only the first option worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**macOS (MacPort)**

If you use MacPort to install mysql, you may find a file named mysqlclient.pc somewhere at /opt/local/lib/mysql8/pkgconfig.

To make pip install mysqlclient successfully, mysqlclient.pc must be found by pkg-config.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/mysql8/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PA
```

should let pkg-config find the mysqlclient.pc

Then try

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

### MacOS - M3 Pro (Using Official MySQL Community Server )

Encountering issues with MySQL on your Mac M3 Pro or Apple Silicon ? As of now, MySQL isn't fully compatible with Apple Silicon when installed via Homebrew. You can verify the compatibility status for MySQL on Apple Silicon [here](https://doesitarm.com/formula/mysql).
To overcome this, follow these steps:

**1. Download MySQL from the Official Website:**

Visit [MySQL's official download page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and fetch the appropriate version for your system.

**2. Specify Environment Variables:**

Manually set the **MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS** and   **MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS** environment variables. In your **~/.zshrc** file, append the following lines (adjust the version number accordingly):
you can find path using following command

`sudo find / -name mysql.h`

```
export MYSQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql-8.3.0-macos14-arm64/include
export MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/mysql-8.3.0-macos14-arm64/include
export MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/mysql-8.3.0-macos14-arm64/lib -lmysqlclient
```

- Run `source ~/.zshrc` in your terminal to reload configuration files

**3. Install the MySQL Client Library:**

Activate your virtual environment and install the MySQL client library using the following command:

`pip install mysqlclient`

⠀  Ensure that you verify your installed version of MySQL and    adjust the paths accordingly. Once these steps are completed,    your MySQL setup should function smoothly on your Mac M3 Pro or    Apple Silicon